# How to get TeamCity builds statistics for last quarter(3 month) from API or DB(SQL)?

Tags: api, teamcity

TeamCity issue tracker link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-50234

I want to calc "builds" latency for last week and compare to avg. last month and avg. last quarter.
last month can be easelly fetch via REST API like so:

```
https://teamcity/app/rest/builds?locator=buildType:(id:<BUILD_ID>)&fields=count,build(number,status,queuedDate,finishDate)
```

Latest entrie from payload is 20170502T131511+0300

But how to fetch more data - for last 3 month?
I have access to SQL DB(We use PostgreSQL) and SQL is good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could come across paginaton of the response: try to include `nextHref` attribute of the response entity (`builds`) for items collections (i.e. use `&fields=count,nextHref` instead of just `&fields=count` and you'll probably get the link to the second page of the output).

It it is your case, following locator dimensions are available to control the number of the builds in response:

- `count:<number>` - serve only the specified number of builds
- `start:<number>` - list the builds from the list starting from the position specified (zero-based)
- `lookupLimit:<number>` - limit processing to the latest N builds only (the default is 5000). If none of the latest N builds match the other specified criteria of the build locator, 404 response is returned

There should be no limitation of the output based on the date, but in case there're some clean up rules configured, there could be no data, obviously.